# How to call php values in javascript/jquery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm using php codeigniter mvc framework. My controller consists of the following code

```
$data2['rows2']=$this->data_model->getYear();
$this->load->view('new',$data2);
```

And my view(in head section) has the following code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 var namesArr = **<?php echo var_dump(json_decode($rows2));?>;**

 var progressTrendsData = [[1304294461000,69,1304899261000,28],[1304294431000,3,1304899161000,32],[1304294431000,3,1304899161000,32],[1304294431000,3,1304899161000,32]];
 var chart;
 var options = {
     chart: {
         renderTo: 'trendsDiv',
         type: 'spline'
     },
     series: [{
     name: '',
     data: []
     }]
 };

 for(var i=0;i<namesArr.length;i++) {
    options.series.push({
            name: namesArr[i],
            data: progressTrendsData[i]
    });
 }

 chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options); 
 });
</script>
```

Is this the correct way to call php values in the script part of view? I wanted the script as a button click event and `var namesArr` should retrieve and store the array `['sdad','sadsad'.....]`. Should i use ajax to do that? If so please give an example for how to use ajax here.

**Updated**

I've tried in the following way but no output showed up.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 //var namesArr = <?php echo var_dump(json_decode($rows2));?>;
 var namesArr = new Array();
namesArr = <?php $rows2; ?>
 var progressTrendsData = [[1304294461000,69,1304899261000,28],[1304294431000,3,1304899161000,32],[1304294431000,3,1304899161000,32],[1304294431000,3,1304899161000,32]];
 var chart;
 var options = {
     chart: {
         renderTo: 'trendsDiv',
         type: 'spline'
     },
     series: [{
     name: '',
     data: []
     }]
 };
 for(var i=0;i<namesArr.length;i++) {
    options.series.push({
            name: namesArr[i],
            data: progressTrendsData[i]
    });
 }
 chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options); 
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your controller do

```
$data2['rows2']=$this->data_model->getYear();
$data2['rowsArray']=json_decode($data2['rows2']);
```

Then in the view try

```
var namesArr = ['<?php echo implode("', '", $rowsArray); ?>']
```

Comment: i've tried the way you mentioned but failed to get the output. I've updated my code

Comment: You updated your code using Farhad's incorrect code. What's the exact output you get with my suggested code?  What error's are you receiving?

Comment: i've tried your example and could succeed partially. When i'm trying to use `var namesArr = ['<?php echo implode("', '", $rowsArray1); ?>']` which stores an array, it displays 22,11,33,44 as output but i wanted to access each value from the displayed string. Is there a way to access each value using indexes?

Comment: by trying `var namesArr = ['<?php echo implode("', '", $rowsArray1); ?>'];` the outcome is `22', '11', '33', '44`. From this i'm unable to retrieve individual values by using `namesArr[0]`

Comment: The beginning and trailing `'` apostrophes are inside the square bracket, verify those are present in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to(in case you are using jQuery):

```
$data2['rows2']=json_encode($this->data_model->getYear());
```

In the view:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 var namesArr =  jQuery.parseJSON('<?php echo $rows2;?>');

 var progressTrendsData = [[1304294461000,69,1304899261000,28],[1304294431000,3,1304899161000,32],[1304294431000,3,1304899161000,32],[1304294431000,3,1304899161000,32]];
 var chart;
 var options = {
     chart: {
         renderTo: 'trendsDiv',
         type: 'spline'
     },
     series: [{
     name: '',
     data: []
     }]
 };

 for(var i=0;i<namesArr.length;i++) {
    options.series.push({
            name: namesArr[i],
            data: progressTrendsData[i]
    });
 }

 chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options); 
 });
</script>
```

Otherwise you may try to eval string from php to json by:

```
var namesArr =  eval('('+<?php echo $rows2;?>+')');
```

After this you should check what contains namesArr variable by using:

```
console.log(namesArr);
```

and check your javascript console (should work in Chrome and Firefox).

Answer (score -1):

You can call php value in JS just inserting the php code into javascript. Try to do this:

```
var namesArr = new Array();
namesArr = <? print_r($rows2); ?>
```

Be sure that **$rows2** returns an array.

Comment: This has many syntax errors...you can't just type `<? [array Obj] ?>` and expect anything right to happen.